# Install packages to "Administrator" location in Extension Manager

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a way that extension packages can be installed using the "administrator" client option or similar in a manifest file? I've made an installer package purely for the backend and I'd like it to show up under the 'Administrator' location in the Extension Manager, but it currently shows up under 'Site'.

I've tried adding a "client" property set to "administrator" in the  element, but the docs are evidently accurate when they state it only works for components. I can work around by modifying the database on install using a scriptfile, but surely it's possible using the manifest alone?

Comment: Tried to find the way myself - no success so far. I believe you could try to implement this behavior and add it to joomla-cms at github.com, but it could be challenging.

Comment: I looked into it around when I asked this question and wouldn't be very difficult to implement; you'd probably have a harder time actually getting it merged than coding it.

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I've meant by this. It's headache. Something like 4/10 for me so far I believe [merged/requested]. And those that really development ones are barely get merged. :(

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I thought let me make a note here. it is still hard coded on [line 574](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/libraries/src/Installer/Adapter/PackageAdapter.php#L574) should any of you like to start the PR, let me know and I will help push ;)

Answer (score 0):

"client" property can be defined in the extension tag. For example:

```
<extension type="module" version="3.5" client="site" method="upgrade">
```

To install the module in the administrator area:

```
<extension type="module" version="2.5" client="administrator" method="upgrade">
```

Comment: I'm not wanting to install a module into the administrator location, I'm trying to install the whole package there.

Comment: Not every asset is oriented for site or administrator areas. I think components or plugins can't be installed to a specific client.

Comment: Components are installed into admin by default, plugins are always in site. This is a package though, it doesn't make sense that a package consisting solely of admin modules can't be installed into the admin location. It's very easily taken care of by modifying the extensions table in the scriptfile, but being unable to do it in the manifest seems a bit of an omission, especially as all packages are installed into the admin folder.